# Executing bat file that contains a timeout from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to execute a bat script that contains a timeout in it. I execute the bat file from node asynchronously but node seem to completely ignore the timeout inside the CMD.

JS FILE:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const util = require("util")
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec)

async function executeBat(){
await exec("C:/PktmonScripts/getPhonesMacScript.bat")
do things
}
```

BAT FILE:

```
timeout /T 40 /NOBREAK > nul
```

P.S: The timeout works when I execute the script on cmd..

Comment: are you calling executeBat() at the end?

Answer (score 0):

check your windows command properly if your bat file waits for this, then the program also waits for complete operation
you need to call the function at the end

```
const fs = require("fs")
const util = require("util")
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec)
     async function executeBat(){
     await exec("C:/PktmonScripts/getPhonesMacScript.bat")
     //I am trying Linux file here but works same as windows
     //await exec("./getPhonesMacScript.sh")
}
executeBat()// -------need to call function at end
```

in sh file with execute permission

```
sleep 30
```

it will sleep for 30 seconds and then the program will be exited